Maven compiler plugin is malware?
I was working 1 year with dependency maven-compiler-plugin.
Tried to pull project from git on new pc and before maven update repo i got warning that maven-compiler-plugin is malicious.
I use org.apache.maven.plugins groupId
Can i use it safe?

This message says no you cannot use it safely: https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-mr9q-2wjg-75g9

But many people use it, its not false warning?

The fact that many people use it doesn't make this a false warning.  In fact, the issue seems to be about a suspicious (malicious?) version of maven-compiler-plugin distributed via npm.  See https://www.sonatype.com/blog/this-week-in-malware-oct-28-22 and https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JS-MAVENCOMPILERPLUGIN-3091064. There is nothing on the Apache Maven site about this.  Yet.

Thank you. So using other version of this dependency should be good, right?

General advice: When asking about problems with dependencies, it is a good idea to add the version of the dependency that caused problems/warnings. Quoting the error message/warning may also provide additional information (hints at why it  is considered problematic, perhaps which system/organization emitted the warning).

No.  The issue is how the dependency is being pulled into your project?  Are you getting it via npm?  If yes, then according to the advisory you should treat your entire machine as having been compromised.

The advisory says: "Any computer that has this package installed or running should be considered fully compromised. All secrets and keys stored on that computer should be rotated immediately from a different computer. The package should be removed, but as full control of the computer may have been given to an outside entity, there is no guarantee that removing the package will remove all malicious software resulting from installing it."

NPM is the issue, not Maven.   I used it safely all the time with Maven.  Why did you ask if you ignore all messages, warnings, and advice?   Use it and live with the consequences if you wish.

Very important: Read the link Stephen C gave: https://www.sonatype.com/blog/this-week-in-malware-oct-28-22 and read the first paragraph: This week in malware, we discovered and analyzed six dozen packages flagged as malicious, suspicious, or dependency confusion attacks in npm and PyPI registries. ...

If you are using maven as your dependency manager you are safe as it will be using the official plugin from apache by default.
Either you specify nothing and let maven provide you with the default (as stated above) or you override the configuration and need to define something along those lines:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.13.0</version>
  ...
</plugin>

make sure you are not pulling the artifact from another groupId. If that's unfortunately the case, you can consider your computer compromised. Review your logs, review your local repo and verify what got downloaded.
